# Combining date and time fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have 3 columns in a table in SQL server 2005.

Column A is datetime, Column B is character field  and Column C is again a datetime field.

How can I combine column A and Column B into column C field?

For example, 
column A (datetime) has a value '2004-01-05 00:00:00.000' , 
Column B (character 8) has a value '09:30:00'

I would like to combine these fields and store this value in Column C
and in this example column C would appear as '2004-01-05 09:30:00'

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean combining a 'datetime' with a 'character' in a 'datetime' field? could you please explain more?

Comment: How do you want to combine Columns A and B?

Comment: You'll probably get decent answers if you edit your question and add some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE table_x set C=A + ' ' + B
```

or if you only want to use a part of the col A use substring()

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following:

```
declare @dt datetime
declare @t varchar(8)

set @dt = '2004-01-05 00:00:00.000'
set @t = '09:30:00'

SELECT CONVERT(char(10), @dt,126) +' ' +@t
```

Produces this result:

```
'2004-01-05 09:30:00'
```